# MongoDB custom sort with multiple key value pairs

Tags: mongodb, sorting, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework, aggregate

List of documents in a collection :-

```
{ _id: '1', task: 'task1', status: 'pending', dayAged: '3' },
{ _id: '2', task: 'task2', status: 'waiting', dayAged: '1' },
{ _id: '3', task: 'task3', status: 'complete', dayAged: '3' }
{ _id: '4', task: 'task4', status: 'waiting', dayAged: '3' },
{ _id: '5', task: 'task5', status: 'pending', dayAged: '2' },
{ _id: '6', task: 'task6', status: 'pending', dayAged: '1' },
```

How can we sort above data based on status and day aged
which should be if the status is pending then according to day aged of that status should be listed eg:-
status **waiting** should be first then **dayAged** after that **pending** then **dayAged** so that i can sort  ascending and descending order of dayAged.

```
{ _id: '4', task: 'task4', status: 'waiting', dayAged: '3' },
{ _id: '2', task: 'task2', status: 'waiting', dayAged: '1' }, 
{ _id: '1', task: 'task1', status: 'pending', dayAged: '3' },
{ _id: '5', task: 'task5', status: 'pending', dayAged: '2' },
{ _id: '6', task: 'task6', status: 'pending', dayAged: '1' },    
{ _id: '3', task: 'task3', status: 'complete', dayAged: '3' }
```

Output should be like this..

```
pend.  3
pend.  2
pend.  1 
wait.  23
wait.  21
wait.  13
done.  8
done.  6
done.  3
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [$addFields](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/addFields/index.html) along with [$switch](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/switch/index.html) to assign "weight" for every status. Once it's done you can [$sort](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/sort/index.html) by this new field and remove it afterwards using [$project](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/project/index.html):

```
db.collection.aggregate([
    {
        $addFields: {
            statusWeight: {
                $switch: {
                    branches: [
                        { case: { $eq: [ "$status", "waiting" ] }, then: 0 },
                        { case: { $eq: [ "$status", "pending" ] }, then: 1 }
                    ],
                    default: 2
                }
            }
        }
    },
    {
        $sort: {
            statusWeight: 1,
            dayAged: -1
        }
    },
    {
        $project: {
            statusWeight: 0
        }
    }
])
```

[Mongo Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/Eb6OO67yg-p)